# css file specific for a controller

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

So in my `routes.rb` file I added this little thingy:

```
namespace :admin do
    get :dashboard, to: 'dashboard#index'
```

Now, I do have `Admin::DashboardController` in my controllers directory, and I added `dashboard.css.less` into `stylesheets/admin`. However this file simply isn't loaded when I go to `admin/dashboard`. What should I do to make this file automatically included? Usually with rails my impression was that proper files are used for controllers without any settings required.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better using the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :dashboard, only: :index #-> url.com/admin/dashboard
end
```

---

**Assets**

Assets are loaded through [`manifest files`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives).

Whenever you compile a "manifest file", the `require` directives tell `sprockets` to concatenate various other files into *that* file; intention being to include one file in your layout (rather than 3 separate files).

By default, only **application** is supported:

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/*
  *= require "x"
*/
```

If you want to add *extra* manifest files, you need to add the file to the precompilation queue, and your layout:

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin/dashboard.js admin/dashboard.css )

# app/assets/stylseheets/application.css
/*
  *= require_tree .
  *= stub admin/dashboard
*/

# app/assets/stylesheets/admin/dashboard.css
/*
  *= require "y"
*/

# app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin/dashboard" %>
```

Comment: ok but usually, eg when i add new model i just add files to stylesheets directory, what is different here?

Comment: @Leo First you read what he linked as _manifest_ file please.

Comment: I forgot to mention... in `application.css`, you'll have `require_tree .` - this adds all the files in your `stylesheets` dir. If you want a file precompiled separately, you have to make it standalone

Comment: @Arup Rakshit this article doesnt really answet my question why isnt this file included by default

Comment: Because you're meant to use "application.css" as a single file. How does Rails know how many "other" files you want? We have 10+ CSS files sometimes - how would the framework know which ones to pull out? You have to first exclude them from application, then explicitly invoke them in the front-end

Comment: stupid as it sounds, with every new model rails do know how many, and which files i do want... i just dont know what is the difference in this case

Comment: The new files for each model are meant to provide individual functionality - split up for those models. By default, they'll all be put into `application.css` / `application.js`.